# Can anyone suggest a DBMS which is fast and efficient at writes?

Tags: sql, database, transactions

I have a project which is going to be write-heavy rather than read-heavy. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for open source DBMS setups which are quick at writes?

It doesn't necessarily have to be a relational DBMS either; I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Some more information about what you're trying to design would be helpful.  This question is somewhat over-broad.

Comment: Agreed. Without any ideas of basic requirements, even if vague, like general read/write ratios, how many writes/sec, and the size of the writes, any suggestion for a specific product below is useless... actually, potentially dangerous to your career!

Comment: I don't think the question is so bad, I'm looking for suggestions not an out and out solution or recommendation. There seem to be so many  hidden away db projects and engines for more mainstream db's that there are likely many that I have yet to hear about. The answer suggesting MongoDB is the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Needs some numbers. Serialized writes of 4GB multimedia files is going to be very different from ten thousand concurrent writes of Twitter messages. Do you need 24/7 uptime, replication, hot backup...

Comment: It's a system where many clients are kept live via a message queue, the scenario will be closer to Twitter scenario with frequent small writes. Speed is important as the clients need to be as close to live as is possible, for that to happen the write need to be quick so message can be added to the queue and picked up by the clients.

Answer (score 7):

I'm quoting below some parts of the conclusion of [NoSQL: If Only It Was That Easy](http://bjclark.me/2009/08/04/nosql-if-only-it-was-that-easy/) (the article is more about scalability but still contains interesting things that apply to your context):

> [...]
>
> The real thing to point out is that if
>   you are being held back from making
>   something super awesome because you
>   can’t choose a database, you are doing
>   it wrong. ***If you know mysql, just use
>   it. Optimize when you actually need
>   to. Use it like a k/v store, use it
>   like a rdbms, but for god sake, build
>   your killer app! None of this will
>   matter to most apps.*** Facebook still
>   uses MySQL, a lot. Wikipedia uses
>   MySQL, a lot. FriendFeed uses MySQL, a
>   lot. NoSQL is a great tool, but it’s
>   certainly not going to be your
>   competitive edge, it’s not going to
>   make your app hot, and most of all,
>   your users won’t give a shit about any
>   of this.
>
> What am I going to build my next app
>   on? Probably Postgres. Will I use
>   NoSQL? Maybe. I might also use Hadoop
>   and Hive. I might keep everything in
>   flat files. Maybe I’ll start hacking
>   on Maglev. I’ll use whatever is best
>   for the job. If I need reporting, I
>   won’t be using any NoSQL. If I need
>   caching, I’ll probably use Tokyo
>   Tyrant. If I need ACIDity, I won’t use
>   NoSQL. If I need a ton of counters,
>   I’ll use Redis. If I need
>   transactions, I’ll use Postgres. If I
>   have a ton of a single type of
>   documents, I’ll probably use Mongo. ***If
>   I need to write 1 billion objects a
>   day, I’d probably use Voldemort.*** If I
>   need full text search, I’d probably
>   use Solr. If I need full text search
>   of volatile data, I’d probably use
>   Sphinx.
>
> [...]

So if a non ACID storage system is an option, I'd look at [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/). If not, without more specific informations, I can't say if one DBMS is really better than another for write-intensive applications. Actually, I think it's more a matter of design/architecture/tuning and tend to agree with the author: 1) use the one you know the most 2) which one you choose won't matter to most apps.

Comment: the question wasnt about scaling.

Comment: Agreed. But there is much more than just scaling concerns in this article and its conclusion. I'll put some emphasis on them.

Comment: People confuse ACID with databases.  You can have ACID without SQL, or vice versa (e.g. mysql).  NoSQL doesn't have to forgo transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Well I have seen the commercial DBs get up 2GB per minute on not particulary impressive hardware. The standard Open Source dbs (MySQL, Postgress even sqlite are not far behind).

For any volume of writes which will give a modern DB trouble there are three things which will affect performance (neither of which depends on the particular DB you choose).

One is basic design, particulary partitioning (spreading your db over several physical disks) and minimising the number of indexes on the tables (for write performance zero indexes is best!).

Two is log placement or if possible log avoidence. Logging is the bottleneck in most RDBMes. Making sure your are logging to dedicated fast disks is one way, turning of logging (varies according to the RDBMS but most support this) for the table, if you 
can afford to lose transactions.

Three is hardware -- lots of memory and lots of fast disks to spread out your I/O load.

There are some exotic options out there if this is still not fast enough.
Buy a z/OS mainframe and run the venerable IMS/DB with the DEDB (Data Entry database) feature. This is about four times faster than any other ACID DB. Buy Oracle's In Memory DB option (used to be HPs TimesTen).

Another possibility if you have some decent queing software avaiable is to capture the data and immediatly place it in a queue. You can then have one or more background processes pulling the data off the queue and doing the actual DB updates in the backgroud.

Answer (score 2):

Database systems can be optimized according to the environment in which they run but the most important is hardware especialy I/O. Use as many disks as you can and set up RAID 10 or RAID 0+1 a s you don't want to calculate parity check everytime DBMS write something into the disk.

Comment: true, we assume that you are not raiding.

mysql has different storage engines  also, such as myisam is pretty fast, but it does table level locking

innodb is slower but more stable and does row level locking.

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) is supposed to be good at this. [Have a look at this post especially.](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging)

Answer (score 0):

Defined "write heavy": billions of rows per day, or write intensive compared to read activity?

Even a "write intensive" database peaks around 15% write because of indexes, duplicate checking, UPDATE..WHERE, etc.

Unless you really are an edge case (mentioned in NoSQL answer above), any DBMS will do because the limit will be hardware not vendor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a mystery question -- If you are doing lots and lots of writes and very few look-ups (reads) and (some) updates) ...

Use a fixed record random access file (Seek() and stuff on a posix platform), a flat file.  If you need indexing, simply index your keys to the flat-file to do reads and updates.

The disadvantage is you need to keep the keys in sync. with the contents on writes and updates.  A pretty simple C++ or other OO class can handle that for you I feel.  Why write indexes if you aren't going to use them?  And, depending on you actual need, you can do away with the indexing all together -- And index at the end of the day or something-k!!

Cheers, w.